# Having to check each response item through JSON

Tags: android, json, jsonexception

I have an application that I am building on my free time and I have it hooked up to a REST API.  It is working properly but I am not sure if this is the "proper" way to check JSON errors.  I am looking for the most efficient and reliable way to check for errors in JSON.  I am trying to improve on my understanding of JSON and I don't want to think I am doing it the best way if it is not. Is this the best way to handle around 20 item response through JSON?

**UPDATE**
I forgot to mention that some of the responses may not have results.  That is also why I am asking this question.

**Snippet** Is this how it is typically done?

```
if (serving.isNull("calories")) {
    mCalories = null;
} else {
    mCalories = serving.getString("calories");
}
```

**Some of the code and their responses** I removed most of the strings.

```
private void getFood(final long id) {
    new AsyncTask<String, String, String>() {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            JSONObject foodGet = mFatSecretGet.getFood(id);
            try {
                if (foodGet != null) {
                    mFoodName = foodGet.getString("food_name");
                    JSONObject servings = foodGet.getJSONObject("servings");
                    Object intervention = servings.get("serving");
                    if (intervention instanceof JSONObject) {
                        arrayOrJson = "object";
                        JSONObject serving = servings.getJSONObject("serving");
                        if (serving.isNull("calories")) {
                            mCalories = null;
                        } else {
                            mCalories = serving.getString("calories");
                        }
                        if (serving.isNull("fat")) {
                            mFat = null;
                        } else {
                            mFat = serving.getString("fat");
                        }
                        if (serving.isNull("carbohydrate")) {
                            mCarbohydrates = null;
                        } else {
                            mCarbohydrates = serving.getString("carbohydrate");
                        }
                        if (serving.isNull("protein")) {
                            mProtein = null;
                        } else {
                            mProtein = serving.getString("protein");
                        }
                        /**
                         * Removed Data
                         */
                    } else if (intervention instanceof JSONArray) {
                        mItem.clear();
                        JSONArray serving = servings.getJSONArray("serving");
                        for (int i = 0; i < serving.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject ser = serving.getJSONObject(i);
                            String DifferentServings = ser.getString("serving_description");
                            mItem.add(DifferentServings);
                        }
                        JSONObject newServing = serving.getJSONObject(mLastSpinnerPosition); // Returning the spinner position. 
                        if (newServing.isNull("serving_description")) {
                            mServingDescription = null;
                        } else {
                            mServingDescription = newServing.getString("serving_description");
                        }
                        if (newServing.isNull("calories")) {
                            mCalories = null;
                        } else {
                            mCalories = newServing.getString("calories");
                        }
                        if (newServing.isNull("fat")) {
                            mFat = null;
                        } else {
                            mFat = newServing.getString("fat");
                        }
                        if (newServing.isNull("carbohydrate")) {
                            mCarbohydrates = null;
                        } else {
                            mCarbohydrates = newServing.getString("carbohydrate");
                        }
                        if (newServing.isNull("protein")) {
                            mProtein = null;
                        } else {
                            mProtein = newServing.getString("protein");
                        }
                        /**
                         * Removed Data
                         */                         
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
                return "Error";
            }
            return "";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            servingAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            setItems();
            saveMeal();
        }
    }.execute();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this example, there's a lot of duplicate code violating DRY principle. I think it is because you model one serving as a special case vs list of servings. Just make it a list with one serving in your REST service.

By errors I guess you meant checking for null or not. If some fields can be missing then you should check. You could abstract it and build entire infrastructure for it, but there are lots of tools which already do that.
I am usually moving this JSON parsing boiler plate code away by using [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) for example. Create a "serving" class containing all these fields and work on serialization and deserialization of this class with the help of `Gson`. 
Bottom line, I would move away JSON parsing (and mapping to POJO) from your business logic, API etc

For Gson you can come up with simple utility class:

```
public class GsonUtil {

    private static final Gson gson;

    static {
        gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    }

    private GsonUtil() {}

    public static String toJson(Object obj){
        return gson.toJson(obj);
    }

    public static <T> T fromJson(String json, Class<T> classOfT){
        return gson.fromJson(json, classOfT);
    }       
}
```

`Gson` also offers infrastructure for implementation of custom serializers and deserializers but I guess in your case it should work without it.

If you have an error from the REST service, you can model it with HTTP response code and add corresponding data transfer object (DTO) to have error message and error code if required.